# Handling Errors from Redux API Call as a Toast

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks, native-base

So I'm trying to figure out the best way to display a `Toast` error and success function when the API call fires from redux.

My line of thinking: Create action for the API call. If successful, then I want the screen to change to the home screen. If it fails, then display the message in a `Toast`.

Here's what some of my actions look like:

```js
export function getTokenAPI(username, password) {
  return async function action(dispatch) {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: t.AUTH_GET_TOKEN });
      dispatch(setLoading(true));

      const { data } = await API.authGetToken(username, password);
      const { success } = data;


      if (success) {
        const { access_token, refresh_token } = data;

        dispatch(setAccessToken(access_token));

        dispatch(setRefreshToken(refresh_token));

        await dispatch(setLoading(false));
      } else if (!success) {
        const { errorMessage } = data;
        throw Error(errorMessage);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(setError(e.message));
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    }
  };
}
```

The `setError` action sets the `error` key to `true` and sets the `errorMessage`. Here's what my screen looks like:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Container, View, Toast } from 'native-base';
import styles from './styles';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { authActions } from '_ducks/auth';

const LoginScreen = props => {
  const { getToken, navigation } = props;
  const { navigate } = navigation;

  const navigateToHome = () => navigate('Home');

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const { error, errorMessage } = props;
    await getToken('sample', 'pass123');
    if (error) {
      Toast.show({
        text: errorMessage,
        buttonText: 'kay',
      });
    } else {
      navigateToHome();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <LoginButton onPress={handleLogin} />
      </View>
    </Container>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getToken: () => dispatch(authActions.getTokenAPI()),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoading: state.authReducer.isLoading,
  error: state.authReducer.error,
  errorMessage: state.authReducer.errorMessage,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(LoginScreen);
```

So if there's an error, then display the toast. If it's successful, navigate to the home screen. Essentially, `error` will not be `true` quick enough to make the check within `handleLogin` work appropriately.

Any recommendations on the pattern or process? Should I be using a `useEffect` hook here?

Comment: You could argue that showing the Toast is a side effect of the redux action and not really related to the React component you showed. Whatever navigateHome() is doing could be done with react-router's push function, called in the redux action - if you're using react-router. Then all LoginScreen needs to do is invoke getToken on mount. Which can be done with a useEffect without dependencies or by using a class component and componentDidMount. I'm suggesting this because handleLogin looks a bit clunky, it's replicating the control flow of the thunk redux action, which is not a good sign.

Comment: thanks @timotgl! i wasn't too familiar with the concept of side effects so you put me on the right path on figuring out a solution.